# What are the supported methods to install and deploy Apache APISIX? How should I install Apache APISIX in an isolated network environment?

Tags: apache-apisix

What are the supported ways to install and deploy Apache APISIX? Is there any corresponding documentation? How should I install Apache APISIX if I am in an isolated network environment?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by an isolated network environment?

Perhaps you could try APISIX stand-alone. https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/2.12/stand-alone/

I think the method of installing and deploying APISIX depends on your needs. I would even recommend using a source installation if you are using it for a personal website, as this gives you early access to the latest features.